# Warning: <td> attribute with missing trailing quote mark

Tags: html

I'm working on an email template and I received I few error once a validated the code:

Warning:  attribute with missing trailing quote mark

Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="columns-container banner">
    <tr>
        <td align"center" valign="top" style="height:235px; width:696px;">
            <a href="http://www.researchnow.com/en-US.aspx" target="_blank">
                <img alt="Thanks for visiting our website" src="http://sigs.researchnow.com/NA_Emails/US_Emails/Healthcare/healthcare_responsive_html_email/banner.jpg" border="0">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You’re using a wrong tool for checking your code. The construct `align"center"` is a violation of specifications, so it should be reported as an error, not as a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the equals sign `align="center"`

`<td align"center" valign="top" style="height:235px; width:696px;">`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I saw, you were missing an = sign after the align attribute in your td tag.

Here's the modified code which works for me:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="columns-container banner">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="height:235px; width:696px;">
            <a href="http://www.researchnow.com/en-US.aspx" target="_blank">
                <img alt="Thanks for visiting our website" src="http://sigs.researchnow.com/NA_Emails/US_Emails/Healthcare/healthcare_responsive_html_email/banner.jpg" border="0">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```